# Markdownで手順をリピートしたい

Tags: markdown

手順書のフォーマットを、エクセルからMarkdown記法に切り替えられないか模索・検討しております。
`手順4: 手順1~3を繰り返す`の`手順1~3`を自動で当てはめられないか、書き方で困っています。
プラグインなど、解決策、回避策をご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんか。

私の作成したい手順書のイメージは以下です。

````
　　　
```markdown:before
1. 手順A
1. 手順B
1. 手順C
1. [STEP1的な何か]〜[STEP3的な何か]を繰り返す ◀️[STEP1的な何か]に章立てのタイトルを入れたい
```
⬇️
```markdown:after
1. 手順A
2. 手順B
3. 手順C
4. 手順A〜手順Cを繰り返す
```
````

なお、私の環境は以下の通りです。

- Visual Studio Code ver.1.8.X
   プラグインの導入は可能です。

検索エンジンで`step repeat manual procedure markdown`等と検索しましたが、
解決に役立つ情報は見つかりませんでした。
[DRYなMarkdownを書こう](http://qiita.com/blackawa/items/8a4d692071534478c8a3)はまさに自分が直面していた課題だったのですが、　　　
`Github`の開発者ページは打ち捨てられてました...

お手数おかけいたしますが、以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

美的な問題はありますが、いわゆるテンプレートエンジンの類はどうでしょうか。

```
1. <%- first = "手順A" %>
1. 手順B
1. <%- last = "手順C" %>
1. <%- first %> 〜 <%- last %>を繰り返す
```

上記とスニペットで使用しているのは [EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs) です。
プログラマならぎりぎり使えるかな、という感じですね。

```js
function render(){
 const md = ejs.render($src.value, {});
 $markdown.textContent = md;
 $html.innerHTML = marked(md);
}
</script>
```

```css
h1{
 font-size: 1em;
}
textarea {
 width: 100%;
 height: 20em;
}
pre, div {
 color: black;
 background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!-- 例示用に GitHub のソースを直接利用。常用不可 -->
<script src="https://github.com/mde/ejs/releases/download/v2.5.5/ejs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>

<h1>ソース（Markdown + EJS）</h1>
<textarea id="$src">
# 変数

1. <%- first = "手順A" %>
1. 手順B
1. <%- last = "手順C" %>
1. <%- first %> 〜 <%- last %>を繰り返す

---
# リスト/繰り返し

<%
 let list = ["手順A", "手順B", "手順C"];
 for(let li of list){
-%>
1. <%- li %>
<%
 }
-%>
1. <%- list[0] %> 〜 <%- list[list.length - 1] %>を繰り返す
</textarea>
<button onclick="render();">変換</button>

<h1>Markdown</h1>
<pre id="$markdown"></pre>

<h1>HTML</h1>
<div id="$html"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

R markdown は試されました？
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/

markdownベースで、動的なレポートを書くにはそれなりに有効そうです。
元のmarkdownを以下のように表現できます。

````
```{python echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
manual = [
    '手順A',
    '手順B',
    '手順C',
]

for i, man in enumerate(manual):
    print("%d. %s" % (i + 1, man))

print("%d. %s〜%sを繰り返す" % (len(manual) + 1, manual[0], manual[-1]))
```
````

---

*以下は私の環境(OSX Sierra + python3 + markdown)で出力した手順です。*

あらかじめ`knitr`パッケージをRでインストールしておき、

```
> install.packages(knitr)
```

PATHに以下のような`knit`スクリプトを置きます

```
#!/usr/local/bin/Rscript
library(knitr)
input <- readLines('stdin')
invisible(knit(text=input, output=stdout(), quiet=TRUE))
```

上のmarkdownを`test.md`としてパイプに渡すと以下のような結果を得られます。

```
$ cat test.md | knit 2>/dev/null | markdown

<ol>
<li>手順A</li>
<li>手順B</li>
<li>手順C</li>
<li>手順A〜手順Cを繰り返す</li>
</ol>
```